# GDK set view to a card

Tags: google-gdk

I am basically trying to figure out how to change the text and the footer text of the current card without creating a new card. What am I doing wrong?

Why is it that the following code does not work ...

```
private void GoogleHatesMe(String s){
  simCard.setText(s);
  simCard.setFootnote(s);
  setContentView(simCard.getView());}
```

And yet this code does work ...

```
private void GoogleHatesMe(String s){
  simView = new Card(this).setText(s).getView();
  setContentView(simView);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simView.invalidate() this will force it to repaint.